# Общая переменная PHP

Tags: php, запрос

Через нативный PHP можно работать с cookies и session довольно прозрачно - и это очень хорошо. Но что если мне нужно работать прозрачно с некоторой переменной, которая должна быть доступна при каждом запросе? Не константа, а именно переменная, которая меняет свое значение от запрос к запросу в не зависимости от того кто и в какой последовательности делает запрос. Например некая переменная $counter, с которой я в каждом запросе могу делать нечто:

```
$counter++;
echo nl2br('Ваш запрос имеет номер '.$counter.PHP_EOL);
```

Конечно есть очевидное решение с использованием БД, но мне интересно именно нативные и прозрачные методы? Есть ли они? И если есть то какие?

P.S. на Node.js как это было очень просто.

Comment: Прям совсем-совсем нативно, не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ее всеравно придется где-то хранить.
Если жестко извращаться, то возьми например опцию  smtp_port и пиши в нее (если ты ее не используешь)

ini_set('smtp_port',$counter);

$counter = ini_get('smtp_port');

Но лучше конечно хранить ее где-то в файле или БД.

А прозрачно работать не получится. Если 10 человек загрузят страницу  у каждых переменная увеличит значение. ПХП то не умеет асинхронно общаться с сервером.

Comment: Очень жаль... Спасибо